# Rails: Routing "Courses" -> "Chapters" -> "Lessons"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

im new to Ruby on Rails. I try to connect 3 tables.

My Models:

Course.rb:

```
class Course < ApplicationRecord
has_many :chapters
has_many :lessons, through: :chapters
end
```

Chapter.rb

```
class Chapter < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :course
belongs_to :lesson

end
```

Lesson.rb

```
class Lesson < ApplicationRecord
has_many :chapters
has_many :courses, through: :chapters
end
```

My Course Controller looks like this:

```
class CourseController < ApplicationController
def index
end

def show

@course = Course.find(params[:id])
@chapters = @course.chapters
@lessons = @course.lessons



end
end
```

and show.html.erb

```
<% @chapters.each do |c| %>
<%= c.chapter %>
<%= link_to "lektionen", c %>
<% end %>
```

I can see a list of my courses. Thats working. Also i can see the chapters. But for any reason it is not forwarding the id for making a relationship between these models.

```
Chapter Controller:
class ChapterController < ApplicationController
def index
end

def show
@chapters = Chapter.find(params[:id])
@lessons = @chapters.lessons
end
end
```

i want to forward the id of the course so that chapters << lessons are the children of courses.

```
-courses 
-- chapters 
--- lessons
```

My schema:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2021_04_11_090326) do

  create_table "chapters", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "chapter"
    t.integer "course_id", null: false
    t.integer "lesson_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["course_id"], name: "index_chapters_on_course_id"
    t.index ["lesson_id"], name: "index_chapters_on_lesson_id"
  end

  create_table "courses", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end

  create_table "lessons", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end

  add_foreign_key "chapters", "courses"
  add_foreign_key "chapters", "lessons"
end
```

My routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'chapter/index'
  get 'chapter/show'
  get 'course/index'
  get 'course/show'
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
  
  resources :course 
    resources :chapter
  resources :lessons
end
```

if i click "courses#show" action i could see the chapters. If i click on one chapter i got this error:

> undefined method `lessons' for #Chapter:0x000055f7aeefbe50

I want to show only lessons which are belongs to a specific chapter and the chapter is related to the course.

But im not in able to get this working.

I hope yo can help me.

Comment: Hi thank you for your reply. But im not familar what you mean with setup. Should i write this into my chapter_controller? For example: @lesson = Chapter.first.lesson?

Comment: I've tried this but i than i got another error: undefined method `each' for #<Lesson:0x00007f6595529d40>. Because i only got one object, right? How can i show all lessons which have for example course_id 1 in the chapter_show action?

Comment: I don't get the modeling at all. Shouldn't it be a heirachy where a course has several chapters and then each chapter has multiple lessons? In that case its completely backwards.

Comment: I agree to @max. I have added an answer with a clean datamodel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should rethink you data model in this case:

**Make it Course -> Chapter -> Lesson**

```
class Course < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :chapters # a course has many chapters. alright
end

class Chapter < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :course # a chapter always belongs to a course
  has_many :lessons # and has many lessons ! check!
end

class Lesson < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :chapter # a lesson belongs to a chapter
  
  # helper method if you want to access course directly from lesson
  def course
    @course ||= chapter&.course
  end
end
```

**Database**
Your database should look something like this:
suggestion -> do not name it `chapter` in chapters table. call it `title` or `name`

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2021_04_11_090326) do

  create_table "courses", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end


  create_table "chapters", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.integer "course_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["course_id"], name: "index_chapters_on_course_id"
  end

      
  create_table "lessons", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.integer "chapter_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["chapter_id"], name: "index_lessons_on_chapter_id"
  end

end
```

With this setup you are ready to go with a good hierarchy.

**Draw the routes:**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :courses
  resources :chapters
  resources :lessons
end
```

if you want to make the hierarchy in the url you could do something more advanced

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # use this if you know what you are doing :D
  resources :courses do
    resources :chapters do
      resources :lessons
    end
  end
end
```

**Your controllers:**

```
class CourseController < ApplicationController
  def index
    courses
  end

  def show
    course
  end

  protected
  # get all courses
  def courses
    @courses ||= Course.order(:name)
  end
  
  # find course by id
  def course
    @course ||= courses.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

**In your view `views/courses/show.html.erb`**

```
<h1><%= @course.name %></h1>
<% @course.chapters.each do |chapter| %>
  <h2><%= chapter.title %></h2>
  <% chapter.lessons.each do |lesson| %>
    <%= link_to "Lesson: " + lesson.title, lesson_url(lesson) %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**N+1 problem:**
To avoid N+1 problem when rendering this hierarchy change your controller and add includes to the query:

```
  def course
    @course ||= courses.includes(chapters: :lessons).find(params[:id])
  end
```

I hope this gives you a good start with a clean data model.

Comment: Hello Simon, wow, thank you very very much. I can see, that i have to learn about this. Could you give me a tip, where i can learn an better understanding of this?

Comment: Have you walked through the guides ? https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Comment: And you should search for some "how to create a blog" in rails tutorials